# Regex query picking up `8 5` when it only partially matches the query

Tags: regex

Ive got a list of addresses including post codes (UK version of zip codes)

I want to only view the rows where the post code value starts with `N` or `NW` like this :

`London, N2 5RW
London, NW8 5RW
London, N1 2HJ
London, N38HG
London, NW88FK`

But somtimes the data is written as `Street, London, England, N2 8GF` so i cant just filter on `London, N`.

To capture the data in the above list ive built the following regex `/\s[N]\w|\d\s|\d/ig`

But it also captures `London, W8 5RW` any ideas why ? (it seems to capture the `8 5` part.

**Update**

Ive made a shared version of my regexr here : http://regexr.com/3ctpk

Comment: What is the programming language/tool?

Comment: `London` is always exist in the string?

Comment: Im going to implement this in a google spreadsheet using the =REGEXMATCH formula. But ive been testing the query in http://regexr.com/

Comment: @Shafizadeh London may not always be in the string

Comment: Try [`,\s*NW?\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/gD1yH2/2). BTW, the formula in Google Spreadsheets uses RE2 regex library, not JS. Real testing should be performed in the Google docs spreadsheet. I do not know if all your records have a comma before the value you are checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for why it was matching incorrectly, you told it to do three separate types of captures:

```
\s[N]\w # [1] Match a single whitespace character (space, tab, etc...), 
        # the character "N", and any single letter or digit or underscore
|       # OR
\d\s    # [2] Match a single digit and whitespace character.
|       # OR
\d      # [3] Match a single digit
```

The conditional, `|`, was causing you problems. In the case of London, W8 5RW, it didn't match on [1], but matched [2] `"8 "` and then [3] `"5"`.

Regexr has a couple of great features that can help you out. One is the actual highlighted blocks in the match, showing you the two separate matches: W[8 ][5]RW. The other is the "Explain" tab at the bottom of the page that basically says what I did above (and had I seen that before I wrote it all out, I could've saved myself some time).

If you want to test for any valid UK postcode that starts with N or NW, use the following pattern (which will work with RE2):

```
\s+NW?\d{1,2}\s*\d[A-Z]{2}
```

I'll let you drop that into Regexr to get the explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `N[W]?\d\s?\d[A-Z]{2}$` which breaks down to...

- `N` - starts with the letter 'N'
- `[W]?` - optional letter 'W'
- `\d` - numeric digit #1
- `\s?` - optional white-space character
- `\d` - numeric digit #2
- `[A-Z]{2}` - two capitalized letters
- `$` - end of the string

That should match all of the UK postal codes listed.

You may need to revise this for other UK postal codes.